# Using easyhtml5video with Weebly

Tags: weebly

I'm using a program called EasyHTML5 in an attempt to upload videos in various formats (so my website visitors will be able to see videos on both PC/Macs and mobile devices as video backgrounds without players) to Weebly Pro.

The code given to users by Easy HTMLtVideo is:

```
<!-- Start EasyHtml5Video.com BODY section -->
<style type="text/css">.easyhtml5video .eh5v_script{display:none}</style>
<div class="easyhtml5video" style="position:relative;max-width:1920px;"><video  autoplay="autoplay" poster="eh5v.files/html5video/lobbyanimation20.jpg" style="width:100%" title="lobbyanimation20" loop="loop" onended="var v=this;setTimeout(function(){v.play()},300)">
<source src="eh5v.files/html5video/lobbyanimation20.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="eh5v.files/html5video/lobbyanimation20.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="eh5v.files/html5video/lobbyanimation20.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<source src="eh5v.files/html5video/lobbyanimation20.mp4" />
</video><div class="eh5v_script"><a href="http://easyhtml5video.com">html5 video converter</a> by EasyHtml5Video.com v3.9.1</div></div>
<script src="eh5v.files/html5video/html5ext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End EasyHtml5Video.com BODY section -->
```

The files EasyHTML5Video produces look like this:
[EasyHTML5 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebvqv.png)

The instructions for EasyHTML5Video say to add a folder, created by the software and called ehv5.files, to the HTML Type folder in Weebly's code editor. However, as far as I can tell, I can only add .html files to that particular folder:

[Weebly screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enem2.png)

I know this is a long shot, but I was just wondering if anyone on this forum has had experience with these two programs and might be able to offer a suggestion. I've posted on Weebly's Community forums and contacted EasyHTML5Video but so far haven't been able to confirm if there's a workaround.

Some references:

```
www.weebly.com
www.easyhtml5video.com
www.brandywine.tv (my website)
```

Thanks so much for your attention.

Robert

Comment: *The instructions for EasyHTML5Video say to add a folder, created by the software and called ehv5.files, to the HTML Type folder in Weebly's code editor.* Can you edit your post to include a link to these instructions? That doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Grisha. The instructions can be found here: http://easyhtml5video.com. At the very bottom of How To Add This Video to HTML Page, it says "this folder should be located in the same folder as your HTML page." I'm wondering if the EasyHTML5 is meant for someone hosting their own website, as opposed to someone like me, who is using Weebly and doesn't have access to the root.

Comment: /Users/robertborowski/Desktop/weeblyhtml.png

Comment: You would basically want to put your video files in the "Assets" folder, like you would with images and stuff.  You might have to adjust all the `src=` portions of the HTML code to make sure they point to the correct location and match up to the paths at which the files in "Assets" will be available.

Comment: Thanks, Grisha. I was thinking along the same lines. The path to the assets in the code editor is /files/theme/filename.extension. I'm very green with code. Would I also need to change the actual letters "src" to something different if I adjust the path files?

Comment: If I follow the path code, I think it would look something like this: <source src="eh5v.files/html5video/files/theme/lobbyanimation20.m4v" type="video/mp4" /> Unless the "src" should be changed to something else.

Comment: I figured it out. After adding the videos to Images (found in Assets, in the Code Editor), all that needs to be done (as Grisha pointed out) is change the code. So one like of source code looks like:

Comment: src: "/files/theme/images/weebly.mp4" and so on. Add playsinline for the iPhone.  Thanks Grisha for pointing me in that direction.  Robert